# WordCamp Asia 2020 - February 21-23

Tags: discussion

## WordCamp Asia 2020 ( Cancelled )

WordCamp Asia has unfortunately **been cancelled** due to health concerns. A post by [Matt Mullenweg](https://wordpress.org/news/2020/02/wordcamp-asia-cancelled-due-to-covid-19/) explains...

> I've arrived at the difficult decision to cancel the inaugural
>   WordCamp Asia event, which was planned to take place in Bangkok on
>   February 21st. The excitement and anticipation around this event have
>   been huge, but there are too many unknowns around the health issues
>   unfolding right now in the region to explicitly encourage a large
>   public gathering bringing together over 1,300 people from around the
>   world.

For more information please read his [full post on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/news/2020/02/wordcamp-asia-cancelled-due-to-covid-19/). There is also 
an official post by the WCAsia team regarding [**ticket and travel refunds**](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/2020/02/12/cancellation/).

---

[WordCamp Asia 2020](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/) is happening in a few weeks at Bangkok, Thailand. [**Tickets are on-sale now**](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/tickets/) and we've provided some helpful information below:

## What is WordCamp?

WordCamps are tech conferences revolving around everything WordPress. They're put together by groups of volunteers who bring like-minded individuals together for a few days of teaching, learning, and fun. The groups of people WordCamps bring together vary widely between super users, developers, first timers, and everything in-between. WordCamps usually consist of multiple talks on several different topics, lunch, and socializing.

## When and Where?

WordCamp Asia will be happening on the weekend of February 21-23. The conference will be held at the True Icon Hall at Iconsiam in Bangkok, Thailand. For more information and directions please visit the [WordCamp Asia Website](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/location/).

## Additional Information

[Contributor Day](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/contributor-day/) will be on the first day of the conference (Feb. 21st) and you will need a separate ticket to attend. The contributor day ticket is free of charge but still needs to be attained.

[The full schedule](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/schedule/) is available online now. This schedule lays out what talks will be happening when and where. They are also tagged with a specific category that talk falls under.

If you have any questions, comments, concerns you can join the [#wcasia WordPress Slack Channel](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) or contact [WCAsia team directly](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/contact/) on their website.

Follow the conference on [twitter](https://twitter.com/WordCampAsia) or activity on the [#WCAsia](https://twitter.com/hashtag/WCAsia) hashtag. [**Grab a ticket while supplies last!**](https://2020.asia.wordcamp.org/tickets/)

---

Feel free to note below if you'll be attending WordCamp Asia or if there's any specific talks you're looking forward to.

Comment: "The conference will be held at the True Icon Hall at Iconsiam." – you may want to add "Bangkok, Thailand" as well